# Send an array to web service without using JSON

Tags: ios, post

I want to send an array via POST to a Django web service from my iOS app, and wanted to know if it was possible without serializing to JSON.

Comment: You have to serialise it to something. What's wrong with JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't have a great recommendation as to alternatives, for completeness here is a short example on how easy you can serialize a dictionary with the iOS integrated libraries (no external lib/tools needed):

```
// Dictionary convertable to JSON ?
if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:dict])
{
  // Serialize the dictionary
  json = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

  // If no errors, let's view the JSON
  if (json != nil && error == nil)
  {
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:json encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", jsonString);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be sending it as a plain text and then parse it at the receiving end and cast it to array again.
But then any developer would hate using it, and as publisher you would hate maintaining it(ever a period of time).